# How to make properties file in Spring boot Primary and secondary

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Hi I am using Spring 4.3.7, java 8 and spring boot, My requirement is I have 2 properties file one inside the classpath and another outside. I was able to load both. using

```
@PropertySources({ @PropertySource("classpath:common.properties"), @PropertySource("classpath:anotherFile.properties") })
@PropertySource(value = {"file:${external.config.location}/config_one.properties"},  ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
```

the input  values of both the file will be almost same eg file naming convention or file create location (besides db details and few other token details)
    what has to be done is if external property file exist read the property value from it or else read from one inside the classpath. is this possible via any annotation in Spring boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works out of the box. The difference is that it does not "alternatively" read prop from one or another source, but it rather reads all properties from the first source, then reads all properties from another (and overrides eventual duplicates), than moves to the third source... and so on and on

There are in total 17 "default" sources and all have its own precedence over the others. See more in docs

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config

Please bare in mind, that those sources are read "from bottom to top", so eg key from internal `application.properties` #15 will be overriden by key from external `appication.properties` #14 and so on.

Comment: tried loading the external file after internal but it always shows properties from internal.